# Missing Text in MySQL Workbench Performance Dashboard

Tags: 22.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I've installed MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 22.04 following the directions [here](https://idroot.us/install-mysql-workbench-ubuntu-22-04/). I'm able to connect to my database server and run queries just fine. However, when I access the Performance Dashboard, most of the text appears to be missing:

[image: screenshot]

When I move my mouse around the screen, a black box appears in the top left corner of the screen, but vanishes too quickly for me to get a screenshot. Any ideas?